# Sqlite "OperationalError: near "05": syntax error"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm working with sqlite and I'm struggling a little bit handling date and time. I have a table created with a field `Date` of type `text`.

I need to set that field to a custom time, f. ex: `'2021-01-18 05:07:37'` that I get with this code (I'm using now datetime just as an example)

```
date = datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print(date)
# 2021-01-18 05:07:37
```

Then I create a record with this date:

```
command = f'''INSERT INTO Twitter (Date, Content)
                VALUES(datetime({date}), "Some cool content")'''
print(command)
# INSERT INTO Twitter (Date, Content)
            VALUES(datetime(2021-01-18 05:13:54), "Some cool content")
conn.execute(command)
conn.commit()
```

This code raises an error:

> OperationalError
> Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> in 
> 2 VALUES(datetime({date}), "Some cool content")'''
> 3 print(command)
> ----> 4 conn.execute(command)
> 5 conn.commit()
>
> OperationalError: near "05": syntax error

I'm not sure what is wrong, I think I'm using sqlite datetime format correctly, but the error seems to be related to the format somehow, any suggestions about how can I solve this?

**EDIT**

I noted that if I add manually the date to the sqlite command, it works nice, like doing this:

```
command = f'''INSERT INTO Twitter (Date, Content)
                VALUES(datetime('2021-01-18 05:07:37'), "Some cool content")'''
```

The issue appears when I dynamically add the datetime as a variable, I'm not sure if I'm missing anything.

Comment: Never use f-strings of other string formatting to construct SQL. It's not safe and leads to errors like your. Ceck the docs of your database adapter to see how to give arguments to `execute()`.

Comment: @KlausD. that seems to be the issue, if I add the valeue manually works without errors

Comment: That's not the issue. You are missing the single quotes (`'`) around date/time in your first example.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the sqlite is not familiar with the `datetime` type of python so by trying to insert `datetime(2021-01-18 05:13:54)` into `Date` field you're receiving `OperationalError: near "05": syntax error` and when you're adding the single quotes like
`'2021-01-18 05:07:37'` the date is converted to a string and able to be inserted into the table.
You can try to do

```
command = f'''INSERT INTO Twitter (Date, Content)
                VALUES(datetime('{date}'), "Some cool content")'''
```

OR

```
command = f'''INSERT INTO Twitter (Date, Content)
                VALUES(datetime("{date}"), "Some cool content")'''
```

Note: the sqlite `datetime` function expecting a string as described here https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html